# How to decode url that include cyrillic in header

Tags: php, opencart

Im using Opencart and normaly when you generate product links you are using

```
$this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $this->request->get['product_id'])
```

and this return you something like this

```
https://www.example.com/матрак-симо-пружина
```

I want to use same method to add link in header

this is my code

```
      $link = $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $this->request->get['product_id']);

      header('Link: '.$link.'; rel=canonical');
      
      header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . ($mask ? $mask : basename($file)) . '"');
      header('Expires: 0');
      header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
      header('Pragma: public');
      header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
      if (ob_get_level()) ob_end_clean();
      readfile($file, 'rb');
      exit;
```

But then in a browser header im getting

```
https://www.example.com/Ð¼Ð°Ñ�Ñ�Ð°Ðº-Ñ�Ð¸Ð¼Ð¾-Ð¿Ñ�Ñ�Ð¶Ð¸Ð½Ð°; rel=canonical
```

If i print_r($link) in my code im getting exactly what i want 'https://www.example.com/матрак-симо-пружина'

so whats the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try urlencode(string $string) for url

Comment: i want to output exactly this https://www.example.com/матрак-симо-пружина in the header i dont want encoded url like: %BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0

Comment: "The URL path name can also be specified by the user in the local writing system. If not already encoded, it is converted to UTF-8, and any characters not part of the basic URL character set are escaped as hexadecimal using percent-encoding; for example, the Japanese URL http://example.com/引き割り.html becomes http://example.com/%E5%BC%95%E3%81%8D%E5%89%B2%E3%82%8A.html. The target computer decodes the address and displays the page."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL